# Error through program ple rectify this one

Tags: trigger

```
trigger ContactCreate on Account (after insert) {

    List<Contact> conList2 = new List<Contact>();
    Map<Id,Decimal> MapAcc = new Map<Id, Decimal>();
    for(Account acc : trigger.new){
        MapAcc.put(acc.Id, acc.Number_of_Locations__c);
    }
    if(MapAcc.Size()>0 && MapAcc!= NULL){
        for(Id accId.MapAcc.keyset()){
            for(i=0;i<MapAcc.get(acc.accId);i++){
                Contact conList = new Contact();
                conList.accId = accId;
                conList.LastName = 'Contact' +i;
                conList2.add(conList);
            }
            if(conList2.Size()>0 && conList2!= NULL){
                INSERT conList2;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SFSE. Please take a [tour] and read [ask]. It would be great if you could give us more insights of what type of error do you receive. It will be much easier to help you then.

Comment: This site isn't meant to be a free coding service, but rather one whose aim is to help you become a better programmer/admin by helping you overcome specific issues. When you're running into an error message, it's important that you provide the _full, unaltered text of the error_ (including the stack trace and pointing out which line in your code is failing is also helpful). If your question sounds too much like a "do my work for me" request (which I think is what this question sounds like at the moment), your question has a high chance of being closed.

Comment: Also, if you have additional information you can add to your question, you should [edit] your question rather than replying in the comments. Comments are temporary, and best used to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Several notes:

## Order Matters

If you're worried about null variables, you need to check them before the size.

### Wrong

```
if(someVar.size() > 0 && someVar != null) {
```

### Right

```
if(someVar != null && someVar.size() > 0) {
```

## Do Not Waste Time

If you initialize a variable, you don't need to check if it's null--you know it is not. Also, no need to check if a list is empty before iterating over it.

## Use The Right Tools

You don't need a map, because it's just wasting time. Use a Map when you need to quickly find a value.

## Do Not Check for Empty DML Lists

It's faster to not check for empty lists, and has no penalties against governor limits when you DML on an empty list.

### Wrong

```
if(!conList2.isEmpty()) {
    insert conList2;
}
```

### Right

```
insert conList2;
```

## Check Null Fields

Always make sure a number field isn't null before you try to do math or Boolean logic on it.

## Do Not DML/SOQL In A Loop

Your DML operation is in a loop, which causes governor limit problems on large data loads.

Also, as a side note, if there's more than one account, then the trigger tries to "insert" existing records, which is itself an error.

### Wrong

```
    for(Id accId.MapAcc.keyset()){
        // ... snip ... //
        INSERT conList2;
    }
```

### Right

```
    for(Id accId.MapAcc.keyset()){
        // ... snip ... //
    }
    INSERT conList2;
```

## Final Version

```
trigger ContactCreate on Account (after insert) {
    List<Contact> conList2 = new List<Contact>();
    for(Account acc : trigger.new){
        if(acc.Number_of_Locations__c == null) {
            continue; // Do not create contacts here
        }
        for(Integer i = 0, s = acc.Number_of_Locations__c, i < s; i++) {
            conList2.add(
                new Contact(
                    AccountId = acc.Id,
                    LastName = 'Contact' + (i+1)
                )
            );
        }
    }
    insert conList2;
}
```